My domain redirects to another domain while accessing http URL - NGINX
In my VPS I have hosted two different domains for eg:
https://example1.in and https://example2.com in single VPS, here I've enabled the SSL certificate for the both.
If I trying to access my domain https://example2.com it works fine but if I remove the s from https for eg: http://example2.com, it will redirect to the https://example1.in.
sites-available and enable for example2.com
server {
    listen 8576;
    server_name example2.com;

    # redirects both www and non-www to https
    return 301 https://example2.com$request_uri;
}

for example1.in
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example1.in;

    # redirects both www and non-www to https
    return 301 https://example1.in$request_uri;
}



Please include your relevant nginx config, the results of curl -I http://example2.com and any other relevant information (such as, are you using a CDN). Once you determine/clarify what is responsible for redirecting (nodejs, nginx, other) you can discount and remove references and tags to the other components.

Not programming or development, but: a request using http://example2.com goes to port 80, not 8576, so your first server block can't receive it. Only server blocks listening on 80 can receive this request, and you only have one such block, so it is the default -- and the default block handles any and all requests not matching a block specifying that hostname and port. However, if you change the request to http://example2.com:8576 THAT will work.

@dave_thompson_085 that should be an answer :). Although I expect there are also many duplicates

Kudos for the comments :). that issues has resolved but if I go through the example1.in in Firefox  browser it says example1.in is almost ready. Upload your index page in order to remove this page. but works in chrome & other browsers.

Any way to get rid of the Apache test page?
when I visit the example1.in it says You may now add content to the directory /var/www/html/. Note that until you do so, people visiting your website will see this page, and not your content.

Just replace this:
return 301 https://example1.in$request_uri;

with this:
return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

